# how to pass javascript variable to Spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Could anyone please tell me how to get javascript variable value in Spring MVC Controller.

```
var countrySelection = "Country Selection List:\n\n";
       for (var i = 0; i < frm.selectedCountryItems.length; i++)
          if (frm.selectedCountryItems[i].checked){
              countrySelection = countrySelection + frm.selectedCountryItems[i].value + "\n";
          }

       alert(countrySelection);
```

I want to pass the value countrySelection to controller

Comment: Are you trying to use AJAX or is this part of a form submission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass this variable as parameter from your post/get request to controller and the access it in controller like :

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public String getCountySelected(@RequestParam(value = "UR_PARAM_NAME") String param){
   ... code goes here
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you are not using ajax and you want to sent extra parameter while form submission :

Add the variable in your form domain class with `@Transient` annotation so that spring wont look for matching element to your database table.

e.g.

```
@Transient
private String countrySelection;
//Setter getter methods
```

And then add form hidden variable in jsp like :

```
<form:hidden path="countrySelection"/>
```

And then set `$("#countrySelection").value(countrySelection);` using your jquery.

In the controller you can access this string with objects getter method.

Comment: @willOEM: I'm not using AJAX as part of form submission only.